# luarocks error clarification

Tags: lua, luarocks

I had installed `luarocks` in my `centos system` after installing lua. But when I run `luarocks` I am getting the following error:

```
Error: LuaRocks 2.0.6 bug (please report at luarocks-developers@lists.sourceforge.net).
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1//luarocks/command_line.lua:141: attempt to call field 'run' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1//luarocks/command_line.lua:141: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1//luarocks/command_line.lua:141>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1//luarocks/command_line.lua:141: in function 'run_command'
    /usr/bin/luarocks:28: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Please let me know what went wrong 
Thanks,

Comment: Do you by any chance have two different versions of LuaRocks installed on your system (one in `/usr`, and one in `/usr/local`)?

Answer (score 2):

LuaRocks author here.

This looks like an environment mismatch, possibly with two different versions of LuaRocks installed in the same machine, and one `luarocks` binary launching modules from another. BTW, LuaRocks 2.0.6 is really old, you should upgrade. Removing all LuaRocks versions from your machine and installing the latest one from http://luarocks.org should fix your problem.